# Mulesoft MuleClient.send() method

Tags: mule

I am currently using the Mulesoft

```
org.mule.api.client.MuleClient.send(...)
```

method for my functional testing. However the method is currently deprecated. What is its replacement?

Comment: You could have had a look at the [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.6.0/org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.java)…

Answer (score 2):

You should use `send(String, org.mule.api.MuleMessage)`. The method has the same name, but it takes a `MuleMessage`. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/api/client/MuleClient.java) at the MuleClient interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sample:
`muleContext` is instance of `MuleContext`:

```
MuleMessage muleMessage = muleContext.getClient().send("vm://address", payload, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: `muleContext.getClient().send()`

Answer (score 0):

```
MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
MuleMessage result = client.send("tcp://localhost:3456", "Message Payload", null);
```